# Rails 6 POST Api to store User Locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I want to store the User location in the background by POST API request, fire by React Native frontend every Hour.

I am planning to create an API to store the Information That I received from the Mobile end.

Should I get the single user id and store separately for each user or I get array of User Ids?

How should I need to store the User Locations?

Comment: This seems wayyy too high level for SO, do you have the api setup at all? Depending on how you're getting their location you can use this https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder to geocode/reverse geocode that data.

Comment: if it is possible to get all user location in one hit then go for all user location saving using rails 6 `insert_all` bulk operation but this involves invoking mobile devices at the same time. The best option is a timer in mobile to send the location to the server every hour and save it a single hand.